How to save multiple plots showing raster layers in a matrix grid into a specified folder at 600 resolution as a jpeg in R
I've plotted multiple rasters into a matrix grid and I'd like to save the plot into a specified folder in my directory. My plots are for a poster presentation at a conference and the images need to be really sharp with a resolution of 600.
I know how to save ggplot objects, but I can't figure out how to save this images with this configuration of R code.
When I run my code for the function jpeg, I get this warning message:
Warning message:
In jpeg("Raster_Layers.jpg", quality = 100, units = "px", bg = "white",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Code:
#Create an empty raster to plot the rasters
r <- raster(ncols=3, nrows=2, xmn=1, xmx=6, ymn=1, ymx=6)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))

#Bind the rasters together in a matrix grid layout of three columns and 2 rows 
m <- rbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
layout(m)

#Select the name the raster layer plot and specifiy to store it in the output folder 
jpeg('Raster_Layers.jpg', 
     quality = 100,
     units = "px",
     bg="white",
     res=600, 
     height=437, 
     width=760,
     file = "/Users/Output")

#Plot the rasters (2 rows by 3 columns) into the grid 
plot(resampled_sss, main = "Mean Sea Surface Salinity (kg/m3)")
plot(resampled_sst, main = "Mean Sea Surface Temperature (°C)")
plot(resampled_chla, main = "Mean Chlorphyll-a (kg/m3)")
plot(depth, main = "Depth (m)")
plot(slope, col=rev(map.pal("viridis",100)), main="Slope (degrees°)")
plot(rugosity, col=rainbow(50), main="Rugosity (degrees°)")
dev.off()

When I try and run my code for the function png, I get this error message
#Create an empty raster to plot the rasters
r <- raster(ncols=3, nrows=2, xmn=1, xmx=6, ymn=1, ymx=6)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))

#Bind the rasters together in a grid layout of three columns and 2 rows 
m <- rbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
layout(m)

options(X11.options = c("-dpi", "600"))

#Select the name the raster layer plot and specifiy to store it in the output folder 
png(file = "Raster_Layers.jpg", 
     name.opt = ".X11.Options",
     envir = .X11env,
     quality = 100,
     units = "px",
     bg="white",
     type = "quartz",
     res=600,
     height=437, 
     width=760)

Error Message:
Error: object '.X11env' not found

Screenshot of my Plotted Raster Layers:


I'm not sure, but I guess that file= is not a proper argument in jpeg function. Have you tried jpeg("/Users/Output/Raster_Layers.jpg",quality = 100,units = "px",bg="white",res=600,height=437,width=760)?

And if they needs to be sharp, replace jpeg() with png()..

@rosapluesch I tried your code and thank you for answering me, it was deeply appreciated. This code ran but when I ran the first plot, I got this error message: plot(resampled_sss, main = "Mean Sea Surface Salinity (kg/m3)")
Error in graphics::par(plt = bigplot) :
invalid value specified for graphical parameter "plt"

@GrzegorzSapijaszko I replaced the function jpeg() with png() and I rean rosapluesch suggestion and I got this error message:Error in check.options(new, name.opt = ".X11.Options", envir = .X11env) :
c("invalid argument name ‘quality’ in 'png, "invalid argument name ‘quality’ in '    width = 760)'")

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? I've included both in the question above. Many thanks for your feedback

@AliceHobbs Just a heads-up, each function has detailed documentation. You can type ?par or ?png to see the available arguments and learn more.

Move the layout definition after png device is created, like:
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
r <- raster(ncols=3, nrows=2, xmn=1, xmx=6, ymn=1, ymx=6)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <- setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r)))

#Select the name the raster layer plot and specifiy to store it in the output folder 
png(file = '~/Raster_Layers.png', 
     units = "px",
     bg="white",
     res=600, 
     height=3000, 
     width=4000)

layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 2, 3, byrow=T))

plot(r1)
plot(r2)
plot(r3)
plot(r4)
plot(r5)
plot(r6)
dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2

And the created image:

Or use stack:
png(file = '~/Raster_Layers.png',
     units = "px",
     bg="white",
     res=600,
     height=2000,
     width=4000)

t <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6)
plot(t, nc = 3, nr = 2)
dev.off()


Created on 2024-10-24 with reprex v2.1.0
